Why can't my FastAPI application find the css file when I rerouted to HTTPS when it could find it using HTTP?
My application is running on an EC2 with amazon linux using Docker and nginx. The front end is located in /app/app/static/ and /app/app/templates/. The routes are mounted in the main python file by:
current_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
templates_directory = os.path.join(current_directory, "templates")
static_directory = os.path.join(current_directory, "static")

app = FastAPI(openapi_url="/openapi.json")

app.mount("/templates", StaticFiles(directory=templates_directory), name="templates")
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory=static_directory), name="static")

index.html works when reaching the website, but get error code 301: Moved Permanently regarding style.css since swapping to https:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">

</head>

Using a logger i have verified that the files do exist in the docker container and have the proper content.
The http part of nginx config looks like this:
http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;

        # Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        # Add the static location block here for both HTTP and HTTPS
        location /static/ {
            alias /app/app/static/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
    }

    # This server block is automatically added by Certbot for redirection
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;

        if ($host = mywebsite.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot

        return 404; # managed by Certbot
    }
}



Has

I have verified the proper permissions to the file.
Tried to rename and move to other directories to check if directory permissions was the problem
Tested trailing and non trailing / in the nginx config

